# How to find if a string S is contained inside a string made of S inserted at any position in S (only once) itself

Tags: string, algorithm

As a first check, since a valid input must be made from the insertion of the string into itself, it must be of size twice the string S.

Eg. If S=abc then ababca or aabcbc should return True but False for input such as abcab, abcxa, abcabcabc.

I have already attempted the naive way of check the substring, if it exists then cut out that part and check if the remaining string matches S. But this fails for some type of inputs.

```
private static void printResult(String s, String p){
    int x = p.indexOf(s);

    if(x<0){
        System.out.println("False");
        return;
    }
    String s1="";
    if(p.length()>=s.length()*2){
        s1 = p.substring(0,x)+p.substring(x+s.length());
        if(s1.equals(s)){
            System.out.println("True");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("False");
        }
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("False");
}
```

Comment: For which inputs does it fails? Show us the code and examples.

Comment: Added the trial code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the first occurence of `s` may not be appropriate in some cases.

Suppose your original word is `w=xyx` (for `x`,`y` some words) then you can insert `w`into itself to produce `xyXYXx` (uppercase to show the insertion). Now you can see that if you try to find `xyx` your algorithm will find it in the first position and then produce `yxx` as the remaining part.

So you need to look at every possible position before concluding.